# Classloader to isolate a jar (class identity crisis)

Tags: java, jar, classloader, conflict

I'm using jarX that has embedded dependencies that conflict with my own dependencies, so I'm creating a classloader to isolate jarX's dependencies from my main classloader.

jarX is outside my app's classpath, but my classes that use jarX's classes are in my classpath, so when I instantiate my classes loaded via the custom classloader, I run into the class identity crisis in the form of ClassCastException as the JVM's version of my classes are considered different from those loaded by my custom classloader.

I found [this blog post](http://giallone.blogspot.ca/2013/01/java-handmade-classloader-isolation.html) where they solved a similar problem by only interacting with the custom classloader loaded classes via reflection, which seems to solve this problem.

It just feels like it should be easier than this.  Does anyone know a better way to handle this problem?

Comment: The simplest solution I currently can think of would be to use the same version of the required library as the one jarX requires. However, this is not always possible due to certain policies. If you have maven (may work in gradle too?) you can specify to exclude certain libraries required by jarX from being loaded and therefore use your interfering library. This, however, is only possible if both jars use the same common interface.

Comment: The issue is that they're embedded and incomplete (missing unused methods), which does make removing the offending classes viable, but that solution was deemed unsuitable for reasons I'm too lazy to go into, so here I am with a broken classloader :)

Comment: Ca you post which jars are in conflict and the full stack-trace, which server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to open jarX, remove the offending classes, and done. It is a bad practice to embed dependencies in a JAR unless that is JAR is meant to be used only as a standalone runnable fat-jar. JARs that are meant to be used as libraries should not embed dependencies.

When you notice that people package third-party classes in their JARs, I'd recommend pointing out to them that this is generally not a good idea and to encourage them to refrain from doing so. If a project provides a runnable fat-jar including all dependencies, that is fine. But, it should not be the only JAR they provide. A plain JAR or set of JARs without any third-party code should also be offered. In the rare cases that third-party code was modified and must be included, it should be done under the package namespace of the provider, not of the original third-party.

Finally, for real solutions to building modular Java applications and handling classloader isolation, check out one of the several [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) implementations or project [Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/).

Answer (score 0):

Can you post which jar is it and what are the classes that it overlaps, with the full stacktrace? Have a look at this [tool](http://jhades.org/documentation.html#warreport) I wrote to generate a list of duplicate classes in the WAR, there is an option to exclude duplicates of the same size.

These are some measures that can be done to solve this:

- Try to reduce the number of duplicates by doing a case by case analysis of why the overlap exists. Add maven exclusions for jars that are complete duplicates.
- Check if there is a version of the same jar without the dependencies that you could use, which jar is it, xerces, etc?
- If there is no jar without dependencies, you can you exclude the other jar that overlaps jarX and see if the application still works. This means all components that need the jar have a compatible version of the jarX library
- Separate the application into two WARs each with the version of the library you need. This will reduce the number of libraries in which

These where measures that are likelly to be more maintainable long-term

**If the previous measures do not work:**

- open the jar, delete the duplicate classes and publish in the maven repository with a different name jarX-patched
- you can configure nexus to serve a patched jar instead of an unpatched jar transparently
- If your container supports OSGI that would be even better, but if you don't use a OSGI container for development as well, then the application would not work in development.